# React Component Names Like BEM

Tags: reactjs

I got some great react best practices are here. Grateful to AirBnB https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react

So... Got this idea like BEM for classes, but use for component names and children. A bit tired of happening to search around components.

Like so.. Component__childName__childName__childName.jsx

I have this idea however and would like to know:

Is this a bad practice?
Are component names going to be come unwieldy?

Sort of links the file names all together when its box in a box in a box in a box.

Could get as short as say:

```
Component__List.jsx
Component__List__Item,jsx
```

UpdAte question:

Could a separate directory for each component be useful? I am seeing that as well indifferent projects.

For example:

```
|-Components
|--ExampleComponent
|---Component.jsx
|---ComponentList.jsx
|---ComponentItem.jsx
|---ComponentItemDetail.jsx
|---Component.scss
|--AnotherOne
|---AnotherOne.jsx
```

And so on...

Comment: You need to frame this as a question. Its not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking for a good naming practice and is it ok to name your components like `Component_User.jsx`, then if it has a header, `Component_User_Header.jsx`, then if the header has a label `Component_User_Header_Label.jsx`. If you are asking smtg else you can just ignore the rest :)

I guess a better approach would be to put related components into a domain folder: such as under `user` directory `index.jsx` would be your main component and `index.css` would be your main css for that component. Then for each subcomponent you can create a similar named files as a sub-directory.

```
user // main directory
  image //sub directory
    index.jsx //component file import index.css
    index.css //css for this component
  header
     index.jsx //component file import index.css
     index.css
  index.jsx //main component file import sub-directories index files to use those components
  index.css
```

Comment: Nice write up here:  https://marmelab.com/blog/2015/12/17/react-directory-structure.html